# Print result based on first character of sub-string in python

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I want to count the number of sub-string within a string in python based on the 1st character (vowel/consonants) of the sub-string. For example, in the string 'Banana', 'an' is a sub-string that started with a vowel 'a', and it appears 2 times, so I want to count it twice. Same for the other combination ('ana'/ 'anan'...etc). And the sub-string can be repeated, meaning 'an' is also shown in 'ana', so it would be counted twice.

But I could only count the number of sub-string (vowel) appears in the string, is there a way to count the number of sub-string based on the 1st character of sub-string? Plus it should be repetitive like the 'an' and 'ana' case discussed above. Currently my code is as below.
Thanks a lot!!

```
string = input() #User input a string with vowel and consonant
def minion_game(string):
    count_v = 0 #count the number of sub-string started with vowel
    count_c = 0 #count the number of sub-string started with consonant
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] == 'a' or string[i] == 'e' or string[i] == 'i' or string[i] == 'o' or string[i] == 'u':
            count_c += 1
        else:
            count_v += 1
    return count_v, count_c
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should separate your problem into two parts:

1. What are the substrings, you want to count?
2. How many times does each substring occur

For the first part, search each vowel in a string and return every substring starting with the vowel by itself and then increasing the length until it reaches end of string. Here is an example implementation for this:

```
def create_substrings(string):
    l = len(string)
    for vowel in "aeiou":
        pos = 0
        while pos != -1:
            pos = string.find(vowel, pos)
            if pos != -1:
                # Found vowel at position pos
                for i in range(pos, l):
                    # yield a string starting at pos and ending at i
                    yield string[pos:i+1]
                pos += 1

for substr in create_substrings("bananaicecream"):
    print(substr)
```

Part 2 should be implemented similarly (using a loop and str.find) and the function be called with every substr returned by the first function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are wanting to individually count every possible substring that starts with a vowel or with a consonant but not include the individual vowels and consonants themselves. Also, I imagine that a list of substrings should probably exclude the string itself, so here is an approach that creates two lists: one of all possible consonant substrings and one of all possible vowel substrings. It uses a simple `if statement` to filter out results that are a single character or the whole string, and then it returns the counts you are looking for based upon the number of elements in each list:

```
def minion_game(userInput):
    string = str.lower(userInput)#convert input to lowercase string
    count_v = []
    count_c = []
    for i in range(2):# run loop twice, once to find vowels, and once to find consonants
        keyRange = "aeiou"
        if i > 0:
            keyRange = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
        for keyLetter in keyRange:#create substring lists
            letter = 0
            while letter != -1:
                letter = string.find(keyLetter, letter)
                if letter != -1:
                    for num in range(letter, len(string)):
                        if len(string[letter:num+1])>1 and len(string[letter:num+1]) != len(string):
                            if i == 0:
                                count_v.append(string[letter:num+1])
                            else:
                                count_c.append(string[letter:num+1])
                    letter += 1
                
    print "All vowel substrings: "+str(count_v)
    print "Total count of vowel substrings: "+str(len(count_v))
    print "All consonant substrings: "+str(count_c)
    print "Total count of consonant substrings: "+str(len(count_c))
    return (len(count_v), len(count_c))
userInput = "Banana"
print minion_game(userInput)
```

Here is the output for this code:

```
All vowel substrings: ['an', 'ana', 'anan', 'anana', 'an', 'ana']
Total count of vowel substrings: 6
All consonant substrings: ['ba', 'ban', 'bana', 'banan', 'na', 'nan', 'nana', 'na']
Total count of consonant substrings: 8
(6, 8)
```